# OpenSSL 1.0.0 when installing anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, anaconda

On Linux I install Anaconda 4.3 for python2.
When trying to run Anaconda after this, I have the following error:

> RuntimeError: You are linking against OpenSSL 1.0.0, which is no longer support by the OpenSSL project. You need to upgrade to a newer version of OpenSSL.

Changing OpenSSL on my system does not fix the issue. Anaconda seems to be using its own openSSL version? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What is the OS and version of OpenSSL? OpenSSL 1.0.0 is so old I'm not sure what Linux uses it anymore. OpenSSL 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 are the ones you will encounter nowadays. You will also see OpenSSL 0.9.8 on OS X and CentOS 5, but Cent is pretty old.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda is indeed coming with OpenSLL 1.0.0.

Adding

```
export CRYPTOGRAPHY_ALLOW_OPENSSL_100=1
```

to `~/.bashrc` fixed the issue by removing the version check.